# WCF Service, is it possible to save a thread and resume it later?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

I have a wcf service I use to run long lived threads (5-10 minutes).  I am passing the function into a new thread in order to keep the end user browser from hanging.

At this point if the application pool recycles I loose the work being done in the thread.

While im sure I could write something into the object handling the work to pick up where it left off through sql.

I was hoping there would be a way to either keep IIS from recycling, or better still resume the thread.

Comment: Can you add some code to your post? It would be really helpful.

Comment: See Windows Workflow Foundation and AppFabric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid that doing [background tasks in an IIS hosted ASP.NET application](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx) is a very bad idea as you have already found out. You might configure the application pool in IIS and disable recycling but that might have some other side effects on your application performance, so you might reconsider moving those background tasks in Windows Services or Console Applications that are scheduled to run with the Windows Scheduler and where you don't have to concern that the AppDomain might be recycled at any time.

Comment: Thanks for the incite guys, I decided to go a different route so even if the service restarts it can pick up where it left off regardless.

Im just going to load all the work needed to do into a SQL table and if the service shuts down use the AppInitialize() to check if anything is left in that table and pick up where it left off.